# How to integrate Rapidminer with Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, integration, rapidminer

I am working in Rapidminer to do some classification. Now I am trying to work in java(eclipse) to make web application in which i will provide that classification. I am not able to integrate rapidminer with java. Can anybody help me in doing this task? I have been working for days on this.
Actually what I want is that to find a simple .jar file and documentation for rapidminer so that i can perform all the tasks which I am performing on GUI of Rapidminer.

Answer (score 1):

just take a look at the RapidMiner [github](https://github.com/rapidminer/rapidminer-studio) repository. There you can find the source code of the open core.
At the end of the overview page you will find links to the RapidMiner [community](https://community.rapidminer.com/t5/Developer-Forum/Frequently-Asked-Questions-Development/m-p/19782) where the process of integrating RapidMiner into other projects is explained.